# Twitter - get user_id or screen_name querying by user e-mail

Tags: email, twitter, userid

I'm trying to get the user_id or screen_name querying per e-mails on Twitter.
We have a website and also a database of users.  I have also all user's e-mail and I'd like to query if they have a Twitter account, and if so, get the screen_name or user_id....

I've read all twitter api documentation and it seems that I can query user only per screen_name or user_id...

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/24142947/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-users-lookup
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/search

Based on this query: api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.xml?user_id=1401881,1401882

I tried this: api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.xml?email=[e-mail]
Then I got this:
"Client application is not permitted to search with specified terms"

So it seems that Twitter knows this parameter "email" (otherwise it should show a error message)

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

That query is probably an internal method, if it's a method at all. Can't you just ask your users for a Twitter handle if they have one? Apparently when they did allows public access, it was mostly [used for spam](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/ac80b4fdf8eb742a). Ultimately, there's no real need to have to find a user's Twitter handle by email when balanced out with the misuse that could be possible. According to the bottom of [this post](http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=353), there may be something coming in the future for authenciated partners.

Comment: that's weird... I just want to query a twitter user by e-mail... I already have the more sensible information, that is the e-mail... Anyway.. Thank you for your reply, keyboardP.